# Convert linq query expression with multiple froms into extension method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble converting this code into extension method syntax:

```
var query = from c in _context.Customers
                        from o in c.Orders
                        where o.DateSent == null
                        select new CustomerSummary
                        {
                            Id = c.Id,
                            Username = c.Username,
                            OutstandingOrderCount = c.Orders.Count
                        };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ReSharper can convert to/from method chains automatically, just in case you weren't aware.

Comment: so can http://www.linqpad.net

Comment: are you sure this query does what you want? I assume you only want a single record for each customer with a count of orders that have a null SentDate.

Comment: The accepted answer on the question is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14849965/15541 correct suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = _context.Customer
  .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.DateSent == null))
  .Select(c => new CustomerSummary
  {
    Id = c.Id,
    Username = c.Username,
    OutstandingOrderCount = c.Orders.Count(o => o.DateSent == null)
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        var query =
            _context.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders, (c, o) => new {c, o}).Where(@t => o.DateSent == null)
                .Select(@t => new CustomerSummary
                                 {
                                     Id = c.Id,
                                     Username = c.Username,
                                     OutstandingOrderCount = c.Orders.Count
                                 });
```