# How do I translate a LINQ expression with more than one `from` from query syntax to method syntax?

Tags: c#, lambda

Iam using the Entity Framework. How would i write the following Linq-Code in Lambda C#?

```
var users = (from u in context.Users.ToList()
                         from e in u.Events
                         where e.EventName == eventName //Name of the Event, the user is related to
                         select u.FirstName + u.LastName).ToList();
```

Can't get through Lambda in this situation.

Comment: As you calling `context.Users.ToList()` anything after will just use delegates and not expressions.

Comment: @Habib: Duplicate, but not closing as the accepted answer is wrong ;p

Comment: @leppie, fair enough I guess :)

Comment: @Habib: Perhaps that was the requirement, but I added a note, never the less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in "Method Chains" (that's what it's called) looks like this:

```
context.Users.SelectMany(u => u.Events
                               .Where(e => e.EventName == eventName)
                               .Select(e => u.FirstName + u.LastName))
             .ToList();
```

Please note that I omitted the call to `ToList()` on `context.Users` because it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I think there is a problem here. EventName does not exist as a property of Users; it is property of Events.

Comment: @daryal: EventName is accessed on the Event, not on a user. You probably commented on the first version of my answer where the `SelectMany` and the `Where` were switched. However, I have long since fixed it. You might want to refresh.

Comment: This should be `SelectMany(u => u.Events.Where(...).Select(...) )`. I agree with daryal's comment.

Comment: @leppie: It's equivalent. `SelectMany(u => u.Events)` returns `IEnumerable<Event>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: No, you are calling `Event.FirstName + Event.LastName` where it should be on `User`. Edit: Made a mistake agreeing with daryal's comment. But the gist is the same.

Comment: @leppie: Indeed, I missed that one. Please check.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Seems the same as my answer now ;p Oh well.

Comment: @leppie: Looks like. But I didn't peak when fixing mine, I promise ;)

Comment: Thank you all guys for the fast help. Got it nearly like that before, but there was 1 error. I'll mark this as answer, coz its the fullest answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
context.Users.SelectMany(u => u.Events.Where(e => e.EventName == eventName).
                                       Select(e => u.FirstName + u.LastName)).
              ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = context.Users
            .Where(u => u.Events.Any(q => q.EventName == eventName))
            .Select(m => m.FirstName + m.LastName).ToList();
```

Update, adding test related classes;

```
public class User
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

and code;

```
string eventName = "a";

List<User> t = new List<User>();

Event event1 = new Event() { EventName = "a" };
Event event2 = new Event() { EventName = "b" };
Event event3 = new Event() { EventName = "c" };

User user1 = new User() { FirstName = "x", LastName = "y" };
User user2 = new User() { FirstName = "x1", LastName = "y1" };
User user3 = new User() { FirstName = "x2", LastName = "y2" };

user1.Events = new List<Event>();
user2.Events = new List<Event>();
user3.Events = new List<Event>();

user1.Events.Add(event1);
user1.Events.Add(event2);

user2.Events.Add(event2);
user2.Events.Add(event3);

user3.Events.Add(event1);
user3.Events.Add(event3);

t.Add(user1);
t.Add(user2);
t.Add(user3);

var bb = t.Where(u => u.Events.Any(q => q.EventName == eventName)).Select(m => m.FirstName + m.LastName).ToList();
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't compile. `Where` expects a predicate, that is a delegate returning `bool`. You have a delegate returning `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: Your last edit will return less results.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth updated and it works.

Comment: @leppie what do you mean by less results?

Comment: @daryal: If you have 2 users and each of them has 3 events with the specified name your query will return two items. The original query will return 6.

Comment: Say 5 users, with 5 events each. You should get 25 results back. Your query will only return 5 results.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Dammit, stop reading my mind! ;p